# Redirecting folder to file download within same folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want my user to type in a simple URL with a folder name and have automatically download a file. For example:

`example.com/file` would redirect them to `example.com/file/text.ext`. One way I thought I could do it is using `.htaccess` file, sadly that generates `too many redirect errors`. My code was:

`Redirect 301 /file /file/text.ext`

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `Redirect` pattern `/file` also matches the destination path `/file/text.ext` . You need to make it so that it doesn't match the target path. You can use `RedirectMatch`  that only matches the `/file` path

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/file/?$ /file/text.ext
```

Make sure to clean your browser cache or use a different browser to test this change.